# How are this helicopter's blades perfectly timed with the camera shutter?

Tags: feature-identification, pilot-technique, blade, throttle

This is a video of the Mi-24 helicopter. The rotor blades appear not to be moving.
Did the pilot and photographer sync the camera and helicopter to make this video and how? I do not know the true source but the video is remarkable.

Comment: I think this should go on video.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26801/62)

Comment: Video is shot at fixed frame rate, so there's nothing the photographer can do to synch with the helicopter.

Comment: @user71659 I'm not convinced. The only answer a videographer could give is basically the comment I posted a moment ago, so a good answer (as has been posted) requires more knowledge about helicopters than about video.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your comment made a mistake about video (which is why it should go in the other SE). While you have to come up with say, 30 images per second, the integration time, or shutter speed, can be much less than 1/30 second. When the shutter speed is << 1/30 s, you can vary its rate within the video frame (at the risk of introducing judder). This is done exactly avoid (or introduce) synchronization or to eliminate things like roll bars on CRTs.

Comment: @user71659 Heh, OK. The question has come up for reopening but I didn't vote either way.

Comment: @DavidRicherby no vote is better then a down vote. Thanks

Comment: We've seen this effect in film/video for years, but what makes this so striking is that newer digital sensors are so fast that they can have an extremely high shutter speed. On an older video camera the blades would just blur to a far greater extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rotor is spinning at 360 RPM, typical of helicopters, that's 6 revolutions per second, and 5 blades go by each revolution.  6 x 5 is 30, so you have 30 blades passing point X in any 1 second period of time.  Unlike film at 25fps, video is shot at 30 fps, in perfect sync with the blade passage, so the blades look stopped.  If the rotor was going a little faster or slower, the blades would start to move.

The video camera is in effect working like a stop action strobe camera.

Comment: Video cameras generate the frame rate from a quartz oscillator, that is very accurate. I think the interesting aspect of this question is, how/why the rotor keeps the spinning rate that accurate. Is is just coincidence, or could such a video be reproduced any time?

Comment: @bogl yes and the helicopter faces directly at the camera at one point leads me to think the pilot may have fine tuned the throttle to the camera.

Comment: The fuel control system on a turbine helicopter regulates a pre-set rotor RPM.  You apply throttle from idle to an operational setting that bring the RPM into the operating range, then fine tune the speed governor with blips of a toggle switch, setting the precise rotor RPM.  When you pull pitch with collective the governor system will add whatever fuel is required to keep that RPM.  That's why the RPM in the video is so consistent.

Comment: so it is on the helicopter not the camera making this question on topic?

Comment: Well.. on topic enough for me.  Some others are a bit more fussy.  For me, it involves a flying machine.  Good enough.